# What is the 'best practice' way of creating an icon button with an SVG?

Tags: css, svg, button, icons

I know of two ways to create an icon button using an SVG:

**Method 1** - Import the SVG into the file and place it as a child of the button, using CSS to switch off the majority of the buttons styles (or restyle to however you need it to look).

**Method 2** - Use the SVG in the buttons `background-image` CSS style, perhaps having the text of the button visually hidden to make the button accessible to assistive technology.

Aside from not being able to use CSS to apply some colour changes to the SVG in method 2, is there any pro's or con's of each approach? Is there a 'best practice' approach to consider?

Answer (score 5):

#### Method 3

Reference a SVG file
or icons in a spritesheet https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/

`<img src='icon.svg'>`

#### Method 4

Inject SVG as DataURI - https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/09-svg-data-uris/

`<img src="data:image/svg+xml;<svg viewBox='' ... </svg>">`

#### Method 5

Use an Object (or Embed) tag

```html
<object data="your.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <img src="yourfallback.jpg" />
</object>
```

#### Method 6

Use a Web Component to load a file and inject with Method #1

```
<load-file src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg">
```

https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

#### Method 7

Use my (UNlicensed pet-project) https://iconmeister.github.io/ `<svg-icon >` Web Component (supported in all modern Browsers) that will include all SVG icon data **in** the source file.

For **every icon** you *can choose* if you want to create bare SVG **Method 1**
or inject the SVG as datauri into an IMG src **Method 4**.

So it is a single Component File download! No external SVGs or any libraries required.

Example code toolbar at: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/5ct36swL/

All SVG can be styled, with attributes **AND** properties **AND** CSS/properties

(This does style Method 4 IMGs, because the whole IMG src is recreated (not on CSS changes!)

[image]